# How to Redirect/go to the User Profile after login page in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to Redirect to the `User Profile` page once the user is logged in with valid `username` and `password`

But when I click the `Login` button, it doesn't go to the `User Profile` (but it changes the `url` as intended (`http://localhost:3000/instructor/banuka`)

It should also display `InstructorLoginFormComponent` which it doesn't. **When I click nothing happens but all I can see is still there is the `login` page**

This is my `InstructorLoginForm.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import InstructorProfile from "./instructor-profile";
import InstructorLoginFormComponent from "./instructor-login-form-component";

export default class InstructorLoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleOnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const path = `/instructor/${this.state.username}`;
    this.props.history.push(path);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            component={props => (
              <InstructorLoginFormComponent
                {...props}
                username={this.state.username}
                password={this.state.password}
                handleOnClick={this.handleOnClick}
                onChangeUsername={this.onChangeUsername}
                onChangePassword={this.onChangePassword}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path={"/instructor/:instructorId"}
            component={InstructorProfile}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the `InstructorLoginFormComponent.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class InstructorLoginFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container h-100" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
          <div className="user_card bg-dark">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">              
            </div>
            <div
              className="d-flex justify-content-center form_container"
              style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
            >
              <form>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-user" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={this.props.username}
                    onChange={this.props.onChangeUsername}
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="username"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-group mb-2">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-lock" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={this.props.password}
                    onChange={this.props.onChangePassword}
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="password"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="custom-control-input"
                      id="customControlInline"
                    />
                    <label
                      className="custom-control-label"
                      htmlFor="customControlInline"
                      style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
                    >
                      Remember me
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
              <Link
                to={`/instructor/${this.props.username}`}
                type="button"
                className="btn login_btn bg-info"
              >
                Login
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the `InstructorProfile.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class InstructorProfile extends Component {
  render(){
      return(
          <div>
              <h1>Welcome to the profile</h1>
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me where I have went wrong and suggest me a good way to redirect after login validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolved As Is

The problems you're experiencing are likely related to your router not being configured correctly. If you want your `InstructorLoginFormComponent` to be rendered on path `/`, you have to put it inside the route like below. You cannot just pass the reference to the component since you need to pass it the username, password, etc props. You should remove it from anywhere else in your render function since you only want it to render when the path is `/`. I also changed your instructor path to use `:id`. When you want to specify a url parameter, you need to use the syntax `/<my_url>:<my_variable_name>`. It's important to put the `/` out front of all your paths because it's a relative path if you don't.

#### New Router Component

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" render={props => (
      <InstructorLoginFormComponent
        {...props}
        username = { this.state.username }
        password = { this.state.password }
        handleOnClick = { this.handleOnClick }
        onChangeUsername = { this.onChangeUsername }
        onChangePassword = { this.onChangePassword }
      />
    )} />          
    <Route path={"/instructor/:instructorId"} component={InstructorProfile} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

#### Updated handleOnClick

```
handleOnClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const path = `/instructor/${this.state.username}`;
  this.props.history.push(path);
}
```

#### Updated Login Button

```
<Link
  to={`/instructor/${this.props.username}`}
  type="button"
  className="btn login_btn bg-info"
>
Login
</Link>
```

### Recommendation Regarding Login

It's important to note that you aren't actually checking the username and password against something on the server. I'm not sure if this is your test code, or if you intend to implement something with REST. However, you should use a button instead of a link that calls a function on click that sends the username and password to the server. From there, it would return if the credentials matched and whether the user would be able to login or not. Then, you would use

```
this.props.history.push(`instructor/${this.state.username}`);
```

to forward the user to the instructor profile page. But you would only want to do that after you have checked their credentials. You would not use a `Link` component to perform those actions. I put an example below.

#### Example login button

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn login_btn bg-info"
  onClick={this.props.handleOnClick}
>
Login
</button>
```

#### New handleOnClick

```
handleOnClick = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //pseudo-code below
  const user = await checkUserCredentialsAndGetUserObject(this.state.username, this.state.password);
  if(user.response === 'success') {
    this.setState({ user });
    this.props.history.push(`/instructor/${this.state.username}`);
  } else {
    flashMessage('The user credentials you entered were incorrect.');
  }
}
```

Comment: According to your `New Router Component` I cannot see the login form any more.

Comment: Are you on path `/`? @user11436513

Comment: I am on path `/login` and cannot see my login form

Comment: So path should be `/login` if you want the login component to render when you're on the path `/login`. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Okay I figured that out, now the other problem is I cannot type in `username` and `password` fields continuously. I think it is because it loses the focus everytime I try to type something

Comment: It *should* work. Can you update the question with your new code (in a new section)?

Comment: It is working, only problem is I cannot type continuously. When I try to type the username, it types one letter and then loses the focus and I have to click on the field again to type another letter and so on...

Comment: Can you `console.log(props)` in `InstructorLoginFormComponent.jsx`?

Comment: I get an array of details on the things (values and functions) I passed through props. But I cannot type continuously without losing the focus.

Comment: @user11436513 I updated my answer to fix a bug. The `component` prop should have been the `render` prop since it's calling a function to render the component.

Comment: Thank you, now it shows the `Instructor Profile` with the message `Welcome to the profile`, but when I reload the page, it disappears... any solution on this?

Comment: Maybe add `exact` in the `InstructorProfile` component? I think you really need some user authentication response from a server to confirm that the username and password is correct. I'm not sure what your new issue is. I would open a new question because I don't think the issues are related.

Comment: can you provide me with a link to authenticate username and password in database and compare that response with user input values?

Comment: @user11436513 I'm not sure there's a tutorial to show you exactly what you need to do. You need to build a REST API (server) and set up a database. However, probably the fastest way would be to pay for Wes Bos's videos. You'll learn how to use React with a Firebase (Google Cloud). I would recommend these Wesbos videos (https://reactforbeginners.com/). After you take his course, you'll be able to easily accomplish this task. I don't work for Wes or know him. It's how I first started with React.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think I know where you're going wrong.

First of all, when you use the exact keyword on a Route, it will **literally** only show when the url matches. So if you want the LoginFormComponent to show in addition to another, you need to remove the exact keyword.

Next, for dynamically rendering profile pages, you are not following how React Router works.

This tutorial gives a good overview: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/

The short of it is, for the Profile page, the path should be

```
<Route path='/instructor/:username' component={InstructorProfile} />
```

Then, in the profile component, set the initial state by accessing the username in the URL with

```
this.state = {
  user: props.match.params.username
}
```

The question is a little vague, but I think this will help with what you're trying to do. Let me know if something is unclear.